# Use Dynamic List when designing custom component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I'm working on a new component in **lightning experience**.

For this new component I need to do something like the Standard component **Tabs**

[image]

As you see, this component can setup dinamically the quantity of tabs and its names.

I was googling a lot but can't find the way to do it.

Any Idea?

**EDIT**

I understand that this component is using the .design file to parameterize the tabs and its contents and can't find the way to do it.

Comment: Give it a try using dynamic component creation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm

Comment: Thanks @Rao but this is not what I'm talking about. Maybe i wasn't clear with my question. 
will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your update, these attributes are set using a design file.

They are known as Design Attributes as part of the Design Resource in Aura Components: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm

Also set as Properties under TargetConfig in the meta.xml file of Lightning Web Components: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/reference_configuration_tags

But if you want to be able to configure design attributes for a custom component as in the image above, that is currently a limitation as as a design attribute supports only attributes of type Integer, String, or Boolean.

One approach for a custom component could be, have a string design attribute/property where you can input a value in a comma separated format like "Relates,Details" and use JS to split the values based on ',' and render the tabs.